# Are draft-dodgers in scope?

Tags: discussion, questions

In the [faq](https://history.stackexchange.com/faq) it says questions about famous people are in scope. Obviously it is clear cut this sanctions be to ask the questions about Hitler or Julius Caesar  say. But while thinking up a question about vietnam draft-dodgers it occurred to me that questions about the actions of individuals who are notable now but not then might be out of scope.

So, are the war records of people who were non-notable during the war ,but later rose to prominence, out of scope? If not, is there any exception based on the historical notability of what they were part of or the extent that we use collected personal anecdotes anyway to create our history of the events.

When you're done with that, you can tell me if I'm allowed to ask whether Ted Nugent shat his pants to get out of vietnam?

Comment: [ask and be damned](http://history.stackexchange.com/questions/7410/ted-nugent-and-draft-dodging)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as your question is asked in a way that can be answered objectively and clearly, then  go ahead. If it is asked in a way that invites specualtion or opinion, then it will have to be close per site guidelines.

Answer (score 0):

The guideline I would use is, "Would a historian be interested in this particular event, given its historical context/relevance even after the original fact?" If yes, then it's on topic. But we don't want to generate "prurient" interest based on "shat."